# Difference between hello/ and hello in file names, URIs

Tags: language-agnostic

What's the difference between using the name of a directory and using it's name with a trailing dash (`hello` vs `hello/`). It seems to matter a lot in web development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it always safe to remove a trailing slash from a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942751/is-it-always-safe-to-remove-a-trailing-slash-from-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

**The trailing slash indicates that "hello/" is a directory.**

A web server that sees "hello/" will either serve you up its directory listing contents or the default page for a directory called "hello".

- If a default document is configured for that directory, the web server serve it up to the client.
- If a default document is not found or is not configured for that directory, the web server will list the directory's contents.
- If there is no default document and the server is not configured to show you directory contents, you will get a 403 (Directory Listing Denied).

**No trailing slash indicates that "hello" is a file.**

A web server that sees just "hello" will try to serve you up a file called "hello".  It it can't get that file, it will give you a 404 (Not Found).