# URL with trailing slash (/) is not rendering in browser properly

Tags: jquery, url, browser

This may be too much info but here you go... User inputs a url and the url is sent to the backend via ajax to confirm it exists. If it does, it returns the url and the contentType (text/html, image/jpeg...ect). Code below is the ajax success callback.

```
var template = 
"<span class='urlFile'>"+data.contentType+'</span>'+
"<span class='urlPath' title="+data.url+'>'+data.url+'</span>';

$(template).prependTo(fieldWrapper);
```

**The problem** is the resulting html renders partially out of order. Below is the output complements of Firebug (Chrome). Note the data.url (http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) is not wrapped in the span.urlPath.

```
<span class="urlFile">html</span>
<span class="urlPath" title="http://api.jquery.com/appendto"></span>
http://api.jquery.com/appendto/
```

Furthermore, when I add in an `alert(template)` I get:

```
<span class='urlFile'>html</span>
<span class='urlPath' title=http://api.jquery.com/prependto/>http://api.jquery.com/prependto/</span>
```

...which is correct. I believe the problem has something to do with the browser rendering the trailing `/`; however, I am not sure how to fix it other than removing the slash.

FYI: Removing the trailing slash seems to fix the problem, ie:

```
var url = data.url.replace(/\/$/,'');
```

... but is it really needed? Sounds like it is a bad idea based on this:

[Is it always safe to remove a trailing slash from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942751/is-it-always-safe-to-remove-a-trailing-slash-from-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the trailing slash.  The browser thinks that you are closing the second `span` element.  To fix this put the `title` attribute in quotes like this:

```
var template = 
"<span class='urlFile'>"+data.contentType+'</span>'+
"<span class='urlPath' title='"+data.url+"'>"+data.url+'</span>';

$(template).prependTo(fieldWrapper);​
```